# Can not save in VB6 on Windows 2019 Server

Tags: vb6

Good Afternoon StackOverflow,
I have an End User who is coding in VB6, coding seem to have no issue but when he saves his project it hangs and eventually times out. The VB6 project running on a Windows XP machine and he saves on a Windows 2019 Server. There were no Windows Update but all of the sudden it can not save. The Windows 2019 was fully patched (Latest June patch) Note: saving his project on the local XP Machine has no problem.

We noticed that the files where open by him on on the Server and we can close the session out on the Server. When this happens we can not delete the project files (.bas) it seem like they are locked. The only way to unlock these files is to reboot the Server. We tried to replicate this on a different 2019 Server and it does the same thing.

Any help on this is greatly appreciate.

Comment: Have you determined what process on the server is holding the file lock? Perhaps an over enthusiastic AV product. https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows/399660#399660

Comment: Yes, we already tried turning off the AV (McAfee) and it did the same thing. Thank you

Comment: Use Process Explorer as Alex suggested.

Comment: What is strange is that if we create a txt file and change it to .bas extension with VB6 running on the XP machine the same thing will happen (that means VB6 did not even have the .bas open, the new .bas will be locked).

Comment: If VB6 is closed and we create the txt file and change it to .bas it works like normally. Seem like VB6 is causing the file lock from the XP machine.

Comment: Just to clarify: You're saying that if VB6 simply runs and you use e.g. Windows Explorer to create a *.txt file outside of the current working folder of VB6 (i.e. the project folder) and rename that (in Explorer) to *.bas, that file is locked? And if you do the same without VB6 running, everything works as expected? As already suggested, use Process Explorer to figure out which process is actually locking the file. I suspect some kind of AV software to interfere with it. Is there some kind of software that monitors your server's shares other than McAfee?

Comment: Any possibility of a VB6 IDE plugin causing this?

Comment: Hel O'Ween, yes, that is correct just creating the .bas from the Windows Explorer will lock the file with VB6 running. Without VB6 running, we can create and delete the .bas file without any issue